# The Number is Greater Than 7X7

Tags: mathematics

> This number is greater than 7x7
>   This number is less than 8x12
>   Its tens digit is greater than its ones digit
>   Its ten digit is even
>   The sum of its digits is 12

What is the number?

Answer (score 11):

I think it's

> $84$

Because

> This seems to be the only number to satisfy all the given criteria

Demonstration

> If we say the number is $x$ then $49 < x < 96$. 
>  The tens digit is even so that the number has to be in the $60$s or $80$s. 
>  The sum of the digits is $12$ which means $x$ is $66$ or $84$. 
>  The first digit is greater than the second so $x=84$.

Comment: This was the answer I came to as well.

Answer (score 5):

The Number is Greater Than $7\times7=49$

The Number is less than $8\times12=96$

Ten Digit is even leaves

> $[60,69],[80,89]$

Tens Digit > ones Digit leaves

> $[60,65],[80,87]$

The Sum of the Digits is Twelve leaves

> $84$

Answer (score 3):

> This number is greater than 7x7
>   This number is less than 8x12

Thus, the number is

> $49 \lt X \lt 96$

The next clue:

> The sum of its digits is 12

leaves the following possibilities:

> $X \in \{57, 66, 75, 84, 93\}$

Add in another clue:

> Its tens digit is greater than its ones digit

and we can pare it down further:

> $X \in \{75, 84, 93\}$

The last clue we use is:

> Its ten digit is even

which leaves only one possibility:

> $X=84$